# Node JS not able to trigger end usinf stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using NodeJS version v6.9.4. I am trying to execute the below sample code. It continuously but not ending the program. Can anyone help me solve my problem.

```
var stdin = process.stdin,
    stdout = process.stdout,
    inputChunks = [];

#stdin.resume();
stdin.setEncoding('ascii');

stdin.on('data', function (chunk) {
    inputChunks.push(chunk);
});

stdin.on('end', function () {
    var inputJSON = inputChunks.join(),
        parsedData = JSON.parse(inputJSON),
        outputJSON = JSON.stringify(parsedData, null, '    ');
    stdout.write(outputJSON);
    stdout.write('\n');
});
```

Comment: How are you running the program? To get `stdin` to end you may need to `C-D`

Comment: Hi @ExplosionPills, I am not able to get your answer. I am running via the windows power shell. If I want to programmatically trigger "end" event, how can I dot it?

Comment: this is a very old issue, but it may help https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/4631

Comment: Have a look at: https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_signal_events